# LocalDB not started in TFS build

Tags: tfsbuild, localdb

I have set up a Continous Integration build for a solution on my TFS server. The build definition triggers some unit tests after the build. The tests make a connection to a LocalDB.

This works fine on my developer machine. But on the build server the LocalDB instance is not started automatically.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh510202%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) I understand that it gets started when access is requested. And this is true for my developer machine but not for the build server.

So my questions are:
What might be the reason that the LocalDB instance is not started on access when used in a TFS build?
Is this scenario working for anybody out there?

Your help is highly appreciated!

---

**What I have checked**

*SqlLocalDb:* I use SqlLocalDb.exe to query the status of my LocalDB instance.

*User account:* The build agent uses the same user account as I use to check for the status of the LocalDB instance.

*Starting by hand:* When I start the LocalDB instance by hand (using `SqlLocalDb start v11.0` just when the build starts) the tests run just fine.

*Post-Build Event:* I can start the LocalDB instance with a call to SqlLocalDb.exe in a Post-Build Event - and it works. But this is not very flexible...

*Application Event Log:* There are no problems reported in the Application Event Log.

**Versions used**

- Visual Studio 2012
- LocalDB from SQL Server Express 2012
- TFS 2012

Comment: When possible the client will log errors into Application Event Log in Windows. Are you finding any clues there?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to check in the Application Event Log - but no, there are no problems reported there.

Comment: There must be some limitations put on the user token inside the TFS build runner process, maybe it lacks delegation privileges, or something like it. Unfortunately I know nothing about TFS.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issues, but I'm using LocalDb 2014 and TFS 2015 with Build.vnext / Preview.